# How to create new node only if node is not existed in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using neo4j and vertx.

I am using neo4j-jdbc.

I managed to create user but how I can "upgrade" this query to create new users(with unique Index) only if that user isnt existed.
The userId should be the primary key.

```
 private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Neo4jRepo.class);
    private Connection conn = null;

    public Neo4jRepo() {
        logger.debug("Neo4jRepo, Init");
        try {
            Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }
    }
..
public boolean addDistanceUserListByForUserId(String userId) {
        try {
            final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( "create (n:User {name:{1}})" );
            ps.setString( 1, "userId" );
            ps.execute();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Thank you,
ray.

Comment: If you are using neo4J as localhost, you should watch for neo4j embedded, way better perfs.

Comment: neo4j will be as an external service. We thought about having it embedded. but than we lose the GUI and other things. do you think embedded is better than ext ?

Comment: Embedded is better fi you are on the same server :) GUI can be retreived using embedded :)

Comment: in case I am doing remote How can I actually get Node by Id using the jdbc connector? any idea how to map it?

Comment: Never use nodeId as data, you should add your own id property and set it unique using constraints. Else you can retrieve a node byt its ID with cypher (start n=node(<id>))

Comment: I am not using it as data.. let's say I want to know if node (by it's id) is already there and in case it is.. how to retrieve the node itself on same transaction ? can MERGE return me the node incase it's already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`:

```
"MERGE (n:User {name:{1}})"
```

[UPDATE 1]

The following is an example of how to modify `addDistanceUserListByForUserId()` so that it returns a `Map<String, Object>` containing the properties of the created/existing `User`.

```
public Map<String, Object> addDistanceUserListByForUserId(String userId) {
    try {
        final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            "MERGE (n:User {name:{1}}) RETURN n" );
        ps.setString( 1, "userId" );
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            return (Map<String, Object>) rs.getObject("n");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) { 
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

[UPDATE 2]

In your specific case, since you have a uniqueness constraint on `:User(name)`, and existing `User` nodes can have properties other than `name` -- the simple query `MERGE (n:User {name:{1}})` can cause a `ConstraintViolation` error if an existing `User` with the same `name` exists but also has other properties.

To get around that, try replacing the `MERGE` statement with this more complex query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:User { name:{1} })
WITH (CASE WHEN n IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END ) AS todo
FOREACH (x IN todo | CREATE (:User { name:{1} }))
WITH todo
MATCH (n:User { name:{1} })
RETURN n;
```

Here is an explanation of this query:

- It uses `OPTIONAL MATCH` so that if the `User` with the specified `name` is not found, the rest of the query is not skipped (but `n` will be `NULL`).
- It then creates a `todo` collection that will tell the `FOREACH` clause whether it should create the new `User` node. The `FOREACH` clause does nothing if the `todo` collection is empty.
- There needs to be a `WITH` clause between a modifying clause (like `FOREACH`) and a subsequent `MATCH` clause. We don't really need to pass anything forward, so we just use `todo` since we already have it handy.
- We need another `MATCH` query because we want to return the node that was either found, or that we just created. But there is no way to get the node that was created by the `FOREACH` unless we do another `MATCH`.

Comment: See my updated answer. I have not tested that code, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: That works but I am using unique constraints on name and I have other property called age. so In case user is already existed with a name but has diff age and I try to merge I get this exception:  Error executing cypher statement(s) [{code=Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintViolation, message=Node 15 already exists with label User and property "name"=[Jossef]}]

Comment: I have updated my answer with a suggestion for you can work around your ConstraintViolation` issue.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`. This will create node if it doesn't exists. If node already exists - then `MERGE` will act like normal `MATCH` operation.

**Important:** you should use only properties with unique constraint in `{}` properties syntax. Neo4j will merge nodes which have same properties in `{}`.

If you have additional data to be set on node *after* merge, then:

`MERGE (user:User {name: "John", age: 20})` - WRONG way. Because there are no node in database with such `name` and `age` property combination and database will try to create that node. And this will result in `ConstraintViolation` because such `name` already exists.

Correct version:

```
MERGE (user:User {name: "John"}) 
SET user.age = 20
```

This version will search node (and create if needed) at first, and only then then set property on that node.